# Can I be forced to do off-site work during my notice period?

Tags: notice-period, expenses, onsite

If I choose to resign from my current position and I need to give a month notice, can they force me to work anywhere other than my designated location of work in the contract? I am concerned that this may be used in a malicious way to hit me for expenses that I do not know if they would reimburse honestly in another month's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your employer can ask you to carry out any duties that they could/would have asked you to carry out prior to your resignation. Ultimately, your role does not change and if that involved working off-site before, then that can continue.

However, with regards to expenses, they have a legal obligation to refund - if you have genuine concerns then you should ensure you collect sufficient evidence to enable you to prove that all your expenses were incurred in agreement with the employer.

The final point is, really, what are your choices? You either stay and work under their conditions, or you simply walk away with the risk that entails (Namely that you won't get paid)

If you have another job secured, walking away, while unprofessional may be an acceptable option for you if you have genuine reasons to do so.

From reading your posts, however, you seem new to the workplace and a little bit paranoid. You may hate your job but it doesn't mean they're malicious - chances are high that you'll work an uneventful notice period and continue your career elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not new to the workplace, but I am new to the way in which they specifically, work. It is a very small company still very much in start-up phase. I'm not being paranoid - my directors have continually proved to be very tight-fisted, rude about clients behind their back (which is natural I suppose) but also have shown contempt quite often despite repeatedly doing good work. It is as if they expect me to do skilled work for unskilled pay whilst also being exceptionally flexible with my time and energy and be satisfied with it. It's just not mutual for me and I'm at my wit's end.